# Javascript framework for Flask

Tags: javascript, flask

I'm new to Flask and frontend javascript frameworks and trying to build nice REST site which will not reload every user click. I now a little bit of jQuery. What is the best javascript framework suited for Flask?

Comment: here is something which I found fairly helpful https://github.com/rxl/angular-flask

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Flask is a microframework, intended for wide use of extensions (see [the list](http://flask.pocoo.org/extensions/) for most known). And also it's JavaScript-agnostic. So you can use any js-framework you want.

jQuery is good and well-known. I would recommend jQuery + Backbone.js for AJAX/REST web applications. Works nice with Flask.

Backbone.js is also well-known and uses RESTful interfaces by default. But it's main purpose is to help you implementing web apps using MVC (model-veiw-controller) approach on client side. MVC approach is mandatory for complex, feature-reach applications, and gives you supportability and code readability.

I thing this will be best choice for you.
(similar frameworks exist of course)

Comment: Also worth noting - if the OP is unsure which JavaScript framework to pick he might check out the framework comparison project [ToDo MVC](http://todomvc.com/).  It has the same app worked up for a bunch of different JavaScript `MV` *cough* SOMETHING *cough*.  Code up a simple back-end to sync To Dos in Flask and then integrate it - see which one he likes best.  Just a thought.

Comment: @SeanVieira Good comment, worthy of being an answer.